# Kubectl doesn't let to authenticate into psql

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, microservices

I'm trying to configure postgres for my k8s. But after launching postgres pod, i recieve an error:

```
"psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "amigoscode" does not exist"
```

Here is my configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: amigoscode
  POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

stateful set:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: postgres
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: postgres
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: postgres
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pc-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
              name: postgres
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 256Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 512Mi
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
```

I'm using kubectl apply -f <folder_name> command to start and build my postgres-pod

Comment: Could you please explain, what command did you run, when you saw your error? Is this something showing in logs during pod start, or something you see when entering the container and trying some command, ...?

Comment: Probably also from where you ran the command.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a service like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

specify the container port into the StatefulSet

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 5432
```

and then access the database with the command:

```
psql -v -U amigoscode --dbname amigoscode -h <host> <<-EOSQL
   <psql lines> 
EOSQL
```